# ¿Cómo implementar la selección multiple o checkbox con $_POST?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Muy buenas.
Investigué sobre las selecciones múltiples por php, no entiendo bien como implementarlo al $_POST en cuando quiero añadir al base de datos vía phpmyadmin, aunque he investigado al respecto, no encuentro los códigos por el caso de selección múltiple (por MySqli Procedural) y tampoco encuentro una solución como puedo relacionar el tipo_cafe con la selección múltiple, no sé si checkbox es el indicado para que se pueda leer los nombres del café para que uno pueda elegir qué sería, también el nombre del usuario quien compra. 
Dejo los códigos, espero que puedan entender mi problema.
Muchos saludos!

```
pruebacafe.php
```

```html
<h1>Cafe</h1>
<form method="POST" action="anadircafe.php" id="pruebacafe">
<p><b>Selección de Cafe</b></p>
Cafe:<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="4"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="5"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="6"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="7"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="8"/><br>
Usuario: <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="4"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="5"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="6"/><br> 
Precio: <input type="text" name="precio"><br>
IVA: <input type="text" name="iva"><br>
Total: <input type="text" name="total"><br>
<input type="submit" name="prueba" value="enviar">
</form>
```

```
anadircafe.php
```

```html
<?php
$msg = $id_cafe = $id_usuario = $precio = $iva = $total = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
 $id_cafe = $_POST['id_cafe'];
 $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
 $precio = $_POST['precio'];
 $iva = $_POST['iva'];
 $total = $_POST['total'];

 if($id_cafe && $id_usuario && $precio && $iva && $total) {

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cafe");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Fallo conexion: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
  } 

  $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO compra_cafe (id_cafe, id_usuario, precio, iva, total) VALUES ('$id_cafe', '$id_usuario', '$precio', '$iva', '$total')");

  if(!$query) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
  } else {
   $msg = "Datos insertados";
  }
 }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

Esta es la tabla correspondiente del tipo_cafe

[image: Tabla tipo_cafe]

```
anadirimplodecafe.php
```

```html
<?php
$msg = $id_cafe = $id_usuario = $precio = $iva = $total = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
 $id_cafe = $_POST['id_cafe'];
 $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
 $precio = $_POST['precio'];
 $iva = $_POST['iva'];
 $total = $_POST['total'];
 $caf = implode("", $id_cafe);
 $usu = implode("", $id_usuario);

 if($id_cafe && $id_usuario && $precio && $iva && $total){
 
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cafe");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Fallo conexion: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
  } 

  $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO compra_cafe (id_cafe, id_usuario, precio, iva, total) VALUES ('$id_cafe', '$id_usuario', '$precio', '$iva', '$total')");

  if(!$query) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
  } else {
   $msg = "Datos insertados";
  }
 }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

**EDIT:** por la función Implode, que es lo generalmente no funciona, al tratar de añadir por los checkboxes, no se pudo añadir por la tabla. Qué es lo que me falta o debo añadir algo más por la función Implode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final,en la comunidad stackoverflow en inglés me ayudó con el problema, la idea es que para tener varios arrays, sea uno o dos o más (ids), era aplicar esta parte, digamos; `$id_cafe = $_POST['id_cafe'][X];` [X] referiendo a [0] para la elección de los values que se ve en el código de `pruebacafe.php`, este es el código aplicado:

```html
<?php
$msg = $id_cafe = $id_usuario = $precio = $iva = $total = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['prueba'])){
 $id_cafe = $_POST['id_cafe'][0];
 $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'][0];
 $precio = $_POST['precio'];
 $iva = $_POST['iva'];
 $total = $_POST['total'];
 //$caf = implode("", $id_cafe); estos implode dejan error solo habria que ignorarla.
 //$usu = implode("", $id_usuario);

 //$caf = array();
 //$usu = array();

 if($id_cafe && $id_usuario && $precio && $iva && $total){
 
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cafe");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Fallo conexion: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
  } 

  $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO compra_cafe (id_cafe, id_usuario, precio, iva, total) VALUES ('$id_cafe', '$id_usuario', '$precio', '$iva', '$total')");

  if(!$query) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
  } else {
   $msg = "Datos insertados";
  }
 }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

Espero que los demás que tengan mi mismo problema en el caso de arrays o tener ids múltiples, puedan ver esta solución que podrá favorecer a la buena comunidad. 
Muchos saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Hola solo tienes que hacer un ciclo a la variable que te almacena toda la información que seleccionaste y almacenaste:

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $id_cafe_arr        = $_POST['id_cafe'];
    $id_usuario_arr     = $_POST['id_usuario'];
    $precio             = $_POST['precio'];
    $iva                = $_POST['iva'];
    $total              = $_POST['total'];
    foreach ($id_cafe_arr as $key => $value) {
        $id_cafe        = $value;

        foreach ($id_usuario_arr as $key1 => $value1) {
            $id_usuario     = $value1;
            if($id_cafe && $id_usuario && $precio && $iva && $total) {

                $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cafe");

                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    printf("Fallo conexion: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                    exit();
                } 

                $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO compra_cafe (id_cafe, id_usuario, precio, iva, total) VALUES ('$id_cafe', '$id_usuario', '$precio', '$iva', '$total')");

                if(!$query) {
                    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
                } else {
                    $msg = "Datos insertados";
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pregunta @Andrés por el id_usuario se tiene que poner igual el $value? o cambiar por $value1? Es que porque el id_usuario tiene igual una tabla completa de los usuarios.

Comment: Hola, ya depende de como vas a realizar tu insersion ya que si vas a registrar los cafes seleccionados a los usuarios seleccionados, ps el primer ciclo (Foreach) te recorrera todos los cafes que seleccionaste, y adentro usas un segundo for each donde recorras los usuarios, usarias $value1 para que no te interfiera con el primer ciclo, igual ya actualice la respuesta.

Comment: Arregle un poco el formulario del pruebacafe.php y eliminando el id del form que no era necesario y también añadí los foreach en anadircafe.php. 
Al rellenar el formulario, no apareció el mensaje (el echo, igual dejé el echo $msg) y en el base de datos no hubo ningún cambio, debe ser el query?

Comment: Lo mas probable es que sea eso, mira te voy a compartir esta clase que hice para conectar con PDO: https://github.com/WookPlay/Class-DB-PDO , solo mira el documento Readme.md, hay esta bien explicado como usarlo y si tienes alguna duda de como usarlo me dices. ya con eso no deberías tener problemas para hacer las inserciones.

Comment: Investigué sobre si habia alguien con el mismo problema que llevo, resultó que había que hacer la función implode, que podría relacionar con los values del checkbox. Digamos para el array del cafe, sería: $id_cafe = implode(',', $_POST['id_cafe']); no sé si es correcto hacerlo al igual que el id usuario o los arrays.

Comment: Añadiré los nuevos codigos, aun asi no funciona con el implode, espero tener otras opiniones acerca de ello. Edito los nuevos codigos.
Saludos!

Comment: Al final creo que investigué, los checkbox se pueden tomarlos como arrays, tomando el ejemplo de otras temas que investigué, no sólo el caso del implode, que todavía no me funciona. El codigo para tomar los checkbox es: `$check_value = isset($_POST['my_checkbox_name']) ? 1 : 0;` o la otra opción: `$check_value = $_POST['my_checkbox_name'] ?? 0;` (parte del Null Coalescing Operator del PHP 7) voy a tratar uno de esas opciones. saludos!

Comment: DAle y nos cuentas como te fue